# Starting jQuery autocomplete immediately after my Ajax call to server

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I bind a `keyup` event to my input to check if the input value's length is 3.
If it is, I make an Ajax call to the server getting the records from my database which start with these 3 character entered and then I start jQuery autocomplete with source - the data from database.

The problem is when the user enters three characters, I get the source for the autocomlete and only when he enters the fourth character the autocomplete starts. Is it possible to change that behaviour and as soon you enter 3 characters and get the source to start autocomplete?

Here is my code:

```
var keypresshandler = function () {
        var  strin = document.getElementById('txtInput').value;
        newstr = strin.replace(/[^\u0400-\u04FF0-9]/gi, '');
        if (newstr.length<3)
        {
                $( "#txtInput" ).autocomplete( "destroy" );
        }  else     
            if (newstr.length==3)
            {   
                 triming();    
            }
    }


    $(function() {    
         $('#txtInput').bind('keyup', keypresshandler);
     });

    function triming() {
         //make asynchronous ajax call to server to get the source of my autocomplete                    
         // alert (mec.length);       
         $( "#txtInput" ).autocomplete({source: mec});
     }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Call `trimming()` after two characters.

The effect you see is that `autocomplete()` just sets up autocompletion, it doesn't "start" it. Autocompletion is started by a keypress handler which `autocomplete()` installs. So you need to install the handler one character "too early".

Comment: no i can't call triming after a two characters because there are two much records!is there any other way

Comment: @MilkaSalkova: Have you tried it? It should only send a request after the next keypress, so it will query with three! If you're still afraid, why not use the `minLength: 3` option?